# php mail not receiving failure deliveries

Tags: php, email

I'm using php mail function to send emails to a rather long mailing list. It works great.

However, I know that many emails in my mailing list are obsolete and yet I'm not receiving a single failure delivery return.

This is what the code of my sent email looks like:

```
To: test@test.be
Subject:  test  
From: <test@test.be>
Reply-to: test@test.be
X-Mailer: PHP/7.0.2
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
boundary="-----=9cc0de4ea510d9961f665cefb88d8c3a"
Message-Id: <20160307160659.59354220C6@xxlplan.ovh.net>
Date: Mon,  7 Mar 2016 17:06:59 +0100 (CET)
X-Ovh-Tracer-Id: 12043469829572602714
```

Above, I replaced the real email address with test@test.be and the email is correct...

Thanks!

Comment: _"I'm not receiving a single failure delivery return"_ how are you checking this?

Comment: Hopefully your `from` and `to` are not really the same email.

Comment: yes "from" and "to" are the same email. Is that the problem ?

Comment: I'm not really checking. I just know that there are at least 15 obsolete email addresses on which I get a failure delivery when I send the email from my inbox.